# Change the font of CKEditor headers and have this reflected in the drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, css, ckeditor

Is there a way I can change the default header fonts (i.e. `h1,h2`) in the editor dialogue for CKEditor so that they appear both inside the text area and the Paragraph Format drop-down menu. I've been going through the css files and put the following code in **/skins/moono/editor.css**:

```
.cke_reset_all h1, .cke_reset_all h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Rockwell, Georgia, Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, 'Times New Roman', serif; 
}
```

but it doesn't take any effect. I'm wondering if it's something I have to do on the Javascript side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place these rules in `contents.css` file in main CKEditor directory:

```
h1, h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Rockwell, Georgia, Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, 'Times New Roman', serif; 
}
```

This will be enough to style headers in format drop down and editor's contents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!important` property in CSS to enforce its usage by Browser like below

```
.cke_reset_all h1, .cke_reset_all h2 {

 font-size: 25px !important;

 font-family: Rockwell, Georgia, Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, 'Times New Roman', serif !important; 

}
```

by writing it as  `!important` . It will overwrite all its previous css.